# How can I use a macro inside another macro in order to concat the definition of the macro to something? C/C++

Tags: c, macros, concatenation, c-preprocessor

I am trying to make a macro that will be take a predefined prefix and concatenate it to the wanted function name in the argument of the macro, but I have been unsuccessful.

For example, while this is the wanted function signature:

```
void somePrefix__someFunc(int a)
```

However, when I run it and check the symbol table of the program I end up with the expansion of:

```
FUNC_PREFIXsomeFunc
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I do this correctly?

The code I was trying to run:

```
#include <iostream>
#define CONCAT(A, B) A##B
#define FUNC_PREFIX somePrefix__
#define FUNC_NAME(_func) CONCAT(FUNC_PREFIX, _func)

void FUNC_NAME(someFunc)(int a)
{
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    FUNC_NAME(someFunc)(2);
    return 0;
}
```

P.S: I tried using the macro without a CONCAT wrapper (directly trying to concat `FUNC_PREFIX##_func`), but it still did not work.

Comment: You need two levels of concat macro https://godbolt.org/z/TzTqPG6Ga (but be aware that using a double underscore is UB).

Comment: Your code works for me with MinGW x64 8.1.0. I do not need another level of macro. Which compiler are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `##` is always applied before the macro "replacement list" is (re)scanned, so in case `CONCAT` is expanded before the other items, we won't get the desired result. Whenever we end up with a `##` in the replacement list during macro replacement, it is then applied before any further replacement.

So you need an additional helper macro to expand the `FUNC_PREFIX`, so that it is expanded before `CONCAT` is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define CONCAT(A, B) A##B
#define CONCAT_EXPAND(A, B) CONCAT(A,B)
#define FUNC_PREFIX somePrefix_
#define FUNC_NAME(func) CONCAT_EXPAND(FUNC_PREFIX, func)

void FUNC_NAME(someFunc)(int a)
{
    printf("%s: %d\n",__func__, a);
}

int main()
{
    FUNC_NAME(someFunc)(2);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
somePrefix_someFunc: 2
```

Comment: Although naming functions through function-like macros is generally a really bad idea...

Comment: Why is it such a bad idea if I may ask?

Comment: @TalAfek Because function-like macros make the code hard to read, hard to maintain, easily lead to bugs. And also because good systems are deterministic and identifier names are mainly there for the benefit of the programmer; so the notion of variably changing identifier names and thereby confuse the programmer is often misguided to begin with.

Comment: Alright, if thats all then in this specific case it actually improves readability :)
Thanks a lot!